# How to apply ng-class using String syntax and array syntax?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-class

I am a beginner in angularjs and I read in the doc of angularjs that `ng-class` can be applied as `string` and `array` syntax. so I was trying to apply the `ng-class` for the below code

(1) Using String Syntax

```
<p ng-class="style">Using String Syntax</p>
<input type="text" ng-model="style" placeholder="Type here">
```

(2) Using array Syntax

```
<p ng-class="[style1, style2]">Using Array Syntax</p>
<input ng-model="style1"
       placeholder="Type here"><br>
<input ng-model="style2"
       placeholder="Type here"><br>
```

I was trying to apply css like

```
.style{
color:red;
}

.style1{
color:blue;
}
.style2{
font-size:30px;
}
```

but failed. I do not know where I am doing mistake.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Post a better description of the problem: what happens? Any error in the colnsole? Your code works absolutely fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/QsAqXdG4TqCImdU2so0j?p=preview

Comment: No error is not there but that CSS classes are not applied on <p> tag

Comment: What do you type in the inputs?

Comment: Color:red , font-size:56px etc

Comment: `ng-class` is used to add CSS **classes**, not CSS styles. Type `style1`and `style2`, and you'll see that those CSS **classes** that you defined are applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have added the ng-model="style" in input. So what ever you type in the input that will become the class for the 'p' tag because ng-class="style".

check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/devjit/wdtk370z/4/

And Type 'style', 'style1', 'style2' in the input field. you will understand what is happening.

```
<div ng-app>
 <p ng-class="style">Using String Syntax</p>
<input type="text" ng-model="style" placeholder="Type here"/>


<p ng-class="[style1, style2]">Using Array Syntax</p>
<input ng-model="style1"
placeholder="Type here"/><br/>
<input ng-model="style2"
placeholder="Type here"/><br/>

</div>
```